# Making y axis dashed in c3js

Tags: d3.js, c3.js

I am trying to make y axis as dashed. Using

> .domain{    stroke-dasharray: 5,5; }

allows the effect but it also adds it to the X axis. I am unable to get an isolation for Y axis.

I tried

```
var xAxis = d3.selectAll('.c3-axis .c3-axis-x');
```

but this also doesnt work. Can someone help me out please.

My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sourabhtewari/94tbbyrd/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the global css dash rule (which thus applies on both x-axis and y-axis):

```
.domain{
  /* stroke-dasharray: 5,5;*/
}
```

And instead focus on applying the css dash rule only on the y-axis:

```
.c3-axis-y {
  stroke-dasharray: 5,5
}
```